# Can I use a 10G optical cable for 1G communications?

Tags: cable

On Amazon, I see MMF optical cables advertised for 10Gbe. (See example [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009ORV6I).)

I'm looking for a 50u MMF optical cable for 1Gbe. Will the 10Gbe cables also work for 1Gbe?

(The cable would be used with the Arista 1000BASE-SX transceiver listed [here](http://www.aristanetworks.com/en/products/transceiversandcables).)

Comment: Just call [Arista Networks](http://www.aristanetworks.com). You've been asking a lot of questions tied to the same topic. In general, when it comes to compatibility and interoperability questions, defer to the switch vendor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the short answer is yes, the connector on the SFP is LC and this is the same as the fibre cable. The fibre supports the same wavelength 50u as the transceiver and is multimode fibre (MMF). You should be good to go with this cable and transceiver combination.

Answer (score 3):

... **yes** to "using that 10GE cable for 1G", but if you intend to connect a 1 GBit/s port to a 10GBit/s port, those two will *not* synchronize to 1 GBit/s by design.

Unlike the usual interconnectivity of copper 10/100/1000 ports, optical SFPs cannot "negotiate" the most common denominator-they just synchronize at their dedicated speed.